# Runnable jar file not finding images even though images exist

Tags: java, jar, export

I've been having a really odd problem when trying to export my project to a runnable jar. I have looked around and made some changes in my code regarding how I fetch my images.

This is the method I use to get an image.

```
public static Image getImage(String name) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(Engine.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + name));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Couldn't load image" + name);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run my jar file through the command prompt I get the following error message.

[image]

Line 81 containing

```
return ImageIO.read(Engine.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + name));
```

I firstly thought that the error was due to the images not following through to the jar file but I checked with archive manager.
[image]

What is the problem that's causing this error to appear?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the path your are refering to. Your set path is not to the directry where the image is( see the error). print your abusulte path to that folder and see where you are missing.

Comment: How do I print the absolute path to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in slash. So the code should be like this:

```
return ImageIO.read(Engine.class.getResourceAsStream(name));
```

Comment: That returns an error saying that the input is null.

Comment: Engine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)

Comment: Still returns the same error message, and it doesn't work in eclipse then.

Comment: Mark the directory with your images as Resources Root. I use Intellij Idea, so I don't know, how do it in Eclipse. But the main idea is the same. Try right mouse click on directory and then find the same statement in popup menu

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the naming of the images. I had written "def" and "hov" with small letters while the image names were "Def" and "Hov".